# How to hide the Feedly sidebar?

Tags: feedly

Is it somehow possible to hide the Feedly sidebar?

It's taking up a lot of space.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click the bottom pin button on the right side of the left sidebar.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot?

Comment: https://feedly.helpscoutdocs.com/article/281-how-to-pin-and-unpin-the-left-navbar